# in qt how to make a button move accordingly when resizing a widget

Tags: qt, resize, move

I wanna do this: When I enlarge my mainwindow pressing and moving mouse, I want the widget(like a button) to move accordingly(not resize the button) to make sure the button is always at the edge of my mainwindow. I can do it in this way:

```
void MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
int x,y,newx,newy,resizex,resizey;
newx = this->width();
newy = this->height();
resizex = newx - mainwindowWidth;
resizey = newy - mainwindowHeight;
x = ui->button->pos().x();
y = ui->button->pos().y();
ui->button->move(x+resizex, y+resizey);
mainwindowWidth = newx;
mainwindowHeight = newy;
}
```

But it's so complex. Does QPushButton have any attribute to do this job easily? Waiting for your answer. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your pushbutton to a layout and add spacers to push the button to the edge.

Heres an example:

```
QHBoxLayout *hlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
ui->verticalLayout->addLayout(hlayout);

QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Button");
hlayout->addWidget(button);
QSpacerItem *item = new QSpacerItem(1,1, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);    
hlayout->addSpacerItem(item);
```

Comment: Could you please give some very simple code to show your point? Thanks, I tried but failed.

Comment: @user2231578 I modified my answer and added an example. Its basically the same for your pushbutton. You can also do it in the designer.